# To update the field in database using Raw SQL?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-update, rawsql

I need to update IsIgnored field based on senderId when I check in where condition,It not identifying senderId which I compared from loop.It throws exception like ambiguous column name 'senderid'.Guide me on this to resolve this issue.

```
  foreach (var senderId in senderIdList)
                    {
                        using (var context = new BSoftWEDIIContext())
                        {
                           var ediDocuments = context.EDIDocuments.SqlQuery("Update EDIDocument SET IsIgnored=1 from EDIDocument edi  inner JOIN  FileDetails files on edi.FileDetailsId = files.Id where edi.IsDeleted = 0 and  edi.SenderID =senderId and edi.DocumentTypeID != 3 and edi.DocumentTypeID != 5 and edi.DocumentTypeID != 2 and edi.IsIgnored = 0 and files.IsDeleted = 0" );

                        }
```

Tried like this:

```
 var ediDocuments = context.EDIDocuments.SqlQuery("Update EDIDocument SET IsIgnored=1 from EDIDocument edi  inner JOIN  FileDetails files on edi.FileDetailsId = files.Id where edi.IsDeleted = 0 and  edi.SenderID ='149825353' and edi.DocumentTypeID != 3 and edi.DocumentTypeID != 5 and edi.DocumentTypeID != 2 and edi.IsIgnored = 0 and files.IsDeleted = 0", new SqlParameter
                            {
                                ParameterName = "senderId",
                                DbType = System.Data.DbType.String,
                                Value = senderId
                            });


  foreach (var senderId in senderIdList)
                    {

                        using (var context = new BSoftWEDIIContext())
                        {
                            var ediDocuments = context.EDIDocuments.SqlQuery("Update EDIDocument SET IsIgnored=1 from EDIDocument edi  inner JOIN  FileDetails files on edi.FileDetailsId = files.Id where edi.IsDeleted = 0 and  edi.SenderID=@senderId and edi.DocumentTypeID != 3 and edi.DocumentTypeID != 5 and edi.DocumentTypeID != 2 and edi.IsIgnored = 0 and files.IsDeleted = 0", new SqlParameter("@senderId", senderId));
```

Comment: What is the `senderId`? If it's a parameter, you need to use `@` prefix and use `SqlParameter`; otherwise put table alias to distinguish it from same column name in other tables e.g. `files.senderId`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the sql parameter to your query.

```
  using (var context = new BSoftWEDIIContext())
                {
                    foreach (var senderId in senderIdList)
                    {
                        context.EDIDocuments.ExecuteSqlCommand("Update EDIDocument SET IsIgnored=1 from EDIDocument edi  inner JOIN  FileDetails files on edi.FileDetailsId = files.Id where edi.IsDeleted = 0 and edi.SenderID=@senderId and edi.DocumentTypeID != 3 and edi.DocumentTypeID != 5 and edi.DocumentTypeID != 2 and edi.IsIgnored = 0 and files.IsDeleted = 0",
                            new SqlParameter
                            {
                                ParameterName = "senderId",
                                DbType = DbType.Int32,
                                Value = senderId
                            });
                    }
                }
```

Comment: edi.SenderID=@senderId - are you sure that you added @ symbol to the param in the sql query?

Comment: added ,now it showing like The data reader is incompatible with the specified 'BSoftWEDII.Data.EDIDocument'. A member of the type, 'Id', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name.

Comment: Try to use ExecuteSqlCommand instead SqlQuery. Also check the types and existence of edi.SenderID, files.Id fields in the database

Comment: Note: you can't return values in your sql (var ediDocuments =) - it will shouldn't work  because it is not SELECT sql query. so you should decide if you want to update rows of select some rows

Comment: can anyone guide my how to mention nullable datetime type in sql parameter , new SqlParameter
                                      {
                                          ParameterName = "startDate",
                                          DbType = System.Data.DbType.DateTime,
                                          Value = startDate
                                      },

Comment: I hope this article should helps - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7497786/passing-null-as-sqlparameter-datetime-value

Answer (score 0):

```
  foreach (var senderId in senderIdList)
  {
    using (var context = new BSoftWEDIIContext())
    {
      var ediDocuments = context.EDIDocuments.SqlQuery($"Update EDIDocument SET IsIgnored=1 from EDIDocument edi  inner JOIN  FileDetails files on edi.FileDetailsId = files.Id where edi.IsDeleted = 0 and  edi.SenderID={senderId} and edi.DocumentTypeID != 3 and edi.DocumentTypeID != 5 and edi.DocumentTypeID != 2 and edi.IsIgnored = 0 and files.IsDeleted = 0" );
    }

  }
```

But this approach has places to possible SQL-injections.

Comment: It not throwing exception but still not gets updated in database

Comment: @Achu_L,try `context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(commandText);`

Answer (score 0):

First thing you should know is [`DbSet.SqlQuery()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbset-1.sqlquery?view=entity-framework-6.2.0) method primarily used to execute `SELECT` statement which returns result set based on corresponding entity type, i.e. `DbSet` name. If you want to execute action queries like `UPDATE` command, you should use [`Database.ExecuteSqlCommand()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.database.executesqlcommand?view=entity-framework-6.2.0) with `SqlParameter[]` array for parameters instead, as provided in example below:

```
string rawQuery = @"Update EDIDocument SET IsIgnored = 1 From EDIDocument AS edi  
                 INNER JOIN FileDetails AS files on edi.FileDetailsId = files.Id 
                 where edi.IsDeleted = 0 and edi.SenderID = @senderId 
                 and edi.DocumentTypeID <> 3 and edi.DocumentTypeID <> 5 
                 and edi.DocumentTypeID <> 2 and edi.IsIgnored = 0 and files.IsDeleted = 0";

using (var context = new BSoftWEDIIContext())
{
     foreach (var senderId in senderIdList)
     {
         var queryParams = new List<SqlParameter>();
         queryParams.Add(new SqlParameter("@senderId", senderId));

         var ediDocuments = context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(rawQuery, queryParams.ToArray());
     }
}
```

**Note:**

The second parameter of both `DbSet.SqlQuery()` and `Database.ExecuteSqlCommand()` methods uses `object[]` array, hence you need to pass parameters into an array instead of using them directly.

Reference:

[Execute Raw SQL Queries Using Entity Framework](http://www.binaryintellect.net/articles/fbc96859-8a31-4735-baeb-7adcbc521b30.aspx)